# Oracle 12c Identity column with Hibernate 5

Tags: spring, oracle, jpa, oracle12c, hibernate-5.x

I am trying to use **Oracle 12c Identity column** feature with `Hibernate-5.0.0.CR4`. I have used the following properties in Spring boot application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
spring.datasource.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

From the [source code](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/Oracle12cDialect.java) of `Oracle12cDialect`, it seemed like it supports identity column. But I am getting the following error while trying to insert a record into a table called `user_preferences`:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;
import org.hibernate.envers.RelationTargetAuditMode;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_preferences")
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "prefId" })
@Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
public class UserPreference {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "pref_id")
    private Long prefId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String key;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String preference;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    public UserPreference() {
    }

    public UserPreference(String key, String preference, User user) {
        this.key = key;
        this.preference = preference;
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

**Exception that I am getting**:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: getLong not implemented for class oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CRowidAccessor
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedAccessor.getLong(GeneratedAccessor.java:436)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedStatement.getLong(GeneratedStatement.java:228)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedScrollableResultSet.getLong(GeneratedScrollableResultSet.java:564)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper.get(IdentifierGeneratorHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper.getGeneratedIdentity(IdentifierGeneratorHelper.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2730)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3300)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:198)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:317)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:272)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:774)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:747)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:752)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1146)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy106.persist(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:291)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy106.persist(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:433)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:436)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:421)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:393)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:506)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy117.save(Unknown Source)
    at nl.yestelecom.phoenix.user.preference.UserPreferenceService.saveUserPreference(UserPreferenceService.java:45)
    at nl.yestelecom.phoenix.controller.UserController.saveUserPreference(UserController.java:34)
```

Please let me know if there is way to use identity column without using database sequences.

Comment: did you find an anwser to your question?

Comment: No, unfortunately, I did not. We resorted to using Oracle db sequence for id generation.

Comment: okay, after spending hours, it worked for me with oracle 12c, ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.0.jar,  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) and spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect, spring boot 2.0.3.RELEASE having hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final-sources.jar

Comment: Thanks for your comment gargkshitiz, I figured out I had left the old dialect in my persistence.xml ... saved me a few hours!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Hibernate 5.0.X does a query trying to get the ID value from the database when you specify GenerationType.IDENTITY. This value is retrieved from a java ResultSet using an appropriate getXXX depending on the type you used to declare your ID. Either resultSet.getString(columnIndex) or resultSet.getRowId(columnIndex) work in my case but RowId cannot be used in a JPA bean.

If you try changing it ID to string it should work, even though it looks like a bug to me:

```
@Id
@Column(name="PRD_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private String prdId;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it as below:

CREATE TABLE identity_test_tab (
  id          NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  description VARCHAR2(30)
);

SQL> INSERT INTO identity_test_tab (description) VALUES ('Just DESCRIPTION');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO identity_test_tab (id, description) VALUES (999, 'ID=999 and DESCRIPTION');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO identity_test_tab (id, description) VALUES (NULL, 'ID=NULL and DESCRIPTION');
INSERT INTO identity_test_tab (id, description) VALUES (NULL, 'ID=NULL and DESCRIPTION')
                                                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("TEST"."IDENTITY_TEST_TAB"."ID")

since always identity column should have value not null

Comment: My question was how I should do this with Hibernate. I am quite familiar with how to use oracle Identity column type in general.